# Center image in div, with same proportions and overflow hidden, and always fill

Tags: html, css

In short, I want to center image in div, Keep proportions, have overflow hidden, and have the image always fill the div.

Here is an example of what i want:

~

[image: what i want]

~

is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you specify the reason you want this done? This may help to better solve the issue. Also, do you want the rest of the image outside of the div to show?

Comment: Do you want the image to resize to div's frame or the div to adapt to the image size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you may possibly be looking for `background-size: cover;` in combination with `background-position: center`.

This means your `div` would have CSS defined like the following;

```
div {
  background: url('image.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Hope that helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may want to put the image as a background inside of a div as a container and then put the text or whatever inside another div?... maybe like this?

```
    .container{
        background:url('image.png') no-repeat;
        width:500px;
        height:500px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    .content{
        width:20%;
        height:10%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
             text here text here text here text here 
        </div>
    </div>
```